# Нужна помощь в записи отправленного пользователем контакта в БД

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Не получается записать конкретное отправленное пользователем сообщение(контакт) в БД. Атрибута text у a.message.from_user нет и я не вижу других способов.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda a: True)
async def inline_buttons1(a):
    user_id = a.message.chat.id
    if a.data == 'private_office':
        markup_send_contact = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        bt1 = KeyboardButton(text='Отправить свой номер телефона', request_contact=True)
        markup_send_contact.row(bt1)
        await bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, MESSAGES['send_contact'], 
                               reply_markup=markup_send_contact, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
        conn = sqlite3.connect('bigben.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO krasusers(user_id, telefone) VALUES(?,?)', (user_id, 
                                                                               a.message.from_user.text, ))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Ну а зачем вы все в один коллбэк запихнули? Контакт должен отправляться одной функцией, отлавливаться контакт другой и в базу записываться третьей

Comment: @MyZik Таким же образом что в моём коде, просто в разных функциях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отловить отправленный пользователем контакт, можете использовать параметр `content_types=["contact"]`, в Вашем хэндлере.

```py
async def create_user(user_id: int, phone: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bigben.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO krasusers (user_id, telefone) VALUES (?, ?)', (user_id, phone))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="private_office")
async def private_office_handler(query: CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        KeyboardButton(text="Отправить свой номер телефона", request_contact=True)
    )
    await bot.send_message(
        query.from_user.id,
        MESSAGES["send_contact"],
        reply_markup=keyboard,
        parse_mode="MarkdownV2",
    )

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def contact_handler(message: Message):
    contact = message.contact
    
    await create_user(message.from_user.id, contact.phone_number)
```